# Updating Ubuntu Webserver

Tags: ubuntu, security, ubuntu-14.04, update

Our webserver is on AWS running on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.  When I ssh into the server I see this message.

> 196 packages can be updated.
>
> 123 updates are security updates.

Should I update our webserver?  Everything is running fine now so I do not wish to run the risk of breaking anything.  Can I just update the security updates?  Is this the correct process for updating?

```
sudo apt-get update        
sudo apt-get upgrade       
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
# restart the server?
```

I suppose I could create an image of the webserver on AWS incase anything goes wrong.

Is there a way I can check to see what the updates are, especially the security ones, so I can see how necessary they actually are?

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not do it.

If your system is a Web servers and everything is fine there is no benefit in upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. Secutity updates for this release will be up to 2019 year, so stay withing 14.04 LTS. You, or someone else, can upgrade it three years later.

Comment: should I do the security updates only?  How do you go about that?

Comment: Yes, definitly do them. Use `apt-get upgrade` and not `dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 to install all available updates and security updates but **without** updating Ubuntu to next LTS version which I don't want because version 16.04 is a little too different and probably involves too much work for me at the moment.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Don't forget to restart or else if you out and then log back in remotely to the server in question via SSH, it will probably still show that there are available updates and security updates even though you just installed them.